# Acceder a JSON Encadenado

Tags: json, lista, lua

Estoy trabajando en el lenguaje lua de CORONASDK y me tope con un JSON de este tipo:

```
[  
   {      
     "data":{  
         "online":true,
         "peerId":1,
         "id":"5af10ec611686d7373de1b98",
         "scriptData":{  
            "PROFILE":{  
               "religion":"Cristiaismo",
               "OS":"Heterosexual",
               "pais":"Colombia",
               "sexo":"Femenino",
               "PP":"Polo Democrático",
               "email":"",
               "maxScore":0,
               "user":"motorolaef31",
               "raza":"Afrodescendiente",
               "lang":"Inglés",
               "edad":"< 18"
            }
         },
         "externalIds":{  

         },
         "displayName":"motorolaef31"
      }
   }
]
```

Necesito acceder a el atributo "PROFILE" cómo podría hacer eso?

Comment: Hola Wzap PepexD, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que llamar la biblioteca json de la siguiente manera:

```
pcall(function() require "json" end)
```

El `pcall` es para capturar el error como `false` no sé si en el caso de CORONA SDK viene esta biblioteca por default.

Luego se procede a leer el archivo dataJson.json (así llamé el archivo que mostraste arriba) en la ruta que lo tengas guardado como sigue:

```
local file = io.open("/miPC/miRuta/dataJson.json", "r")
local data = file:read("*a")
```

Finalmente usamos la función `decode` de la biblioteca `json` con el archivo leído previamente

```
tb = json.decode(data)
```

Ahora viene la parte de entender cómo leer la tabla que se ha generado en Lua

```
for k, v in pairs(tb) do print(k,v) end
-- se imprime: 1, table: 0x35ce7838
```

Implica que hay una tabla dentro de los corchetes [] en tb

Realiza las siguientes consultas en forma secuencial y verás como puedes obtener los atributos en el archivo original json

```
for k, v in pairs(tb[1]) do print(k,v) end
-- se imprime: data,    table: 0x35ce7698

for k, v in pairs(tb[1]["data"]) do print(k,v) end
--[[
    ------------
    Se imprime:
    ------------
    scriptData  table: 0x35ce7760
    peerId  1
    id  5af10ec611686d7373de1b98
    online  true
    externalIds table: 0x35ce7cc0
    displayName motorolaef31
]]

for k, v in pairs(tb[1]["data"]["scriptData"]) do print(k,v) end
-- se imprime: PROFILE  table: 0x35ce78a0

for k, v in pairs(tb[1]["data"]["scriptData"]["PROFILE"]) do print(k,v) end
--[[
    ------------
    Se imprime:
    ------------
    religion    Cristiaismo
    OS  Heterosexual
    pais    Colombia
    maxScore    0
    PP  Polo Democrático
    email   
    sexo    Femenino
    user    motorolaef31
    raza    Afrodescendiente
    lang    Inglés
    edad    < 18
]]
```